# Estimate seconds left (based on time & progress)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to estimate how many seconds is left of an MSI installation. Though I know this will not be accurate, my calculation seems more off than it should be - how can I improve? One problem is that often I find that the progress rockets from ~0% to ~95% which for a very long time evaluates to 0 seconds left.

I get the progress event from the MSIs, and each time progress is updated I do the following:

```
    private int CalculateSecondsLeft(DateTime start, int overallProgress)
    {
        lock (this)
        {         
            if (overallProgress == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            var timeSpent = DateTime.Now - start;
            double cal1 = timeSpent.TotalSeconds / overallProgress;
            double cal2 = cal1 * (100 - overallProgress);
            return (int)cal2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I never liked those progress bars. I'm a fan of the "checking off a to-do list" installers.

Comment: Me too. But we have an interaction designer who I must listen to.

Comment: You code seems to work ok: http://rextester.com/PJG71340